# Team Foundation Server Build variables

Tags: .net, tfs, build-automation

Does anyone know (or know where to find, couldn't myself) what variables I can use on a TFSBuild.proj file for my automated builds?

For example, $(SolutionRoot) gives me the path to all my source files, but I want to copy the built solution from the release directory (ie: \Nightly Build20090127.7\Release\_PublishedWebsites) and I can't find which variable would give me that directory.

To sumarize, I'd like to know the variable for the release directory of an automated build, but would also appreciate a list of other variables I can use (I am using tfs 2008)

Comment: Team Foundation Build environment variables: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850448.aspx

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Take a look at a blog post I did a while ago when I was trying to figure all this out:

[30 Useful Team Build Properties](http://www.woodwardweb.com/vsts/30_useful_team.html)

Also Aaron Hallberg (Lead for the TFS Build Team), has since documented a huge set of properties - not just values but also extensibility properties (i.e. ones that you can set to certain values to control the build process) which is a great reference:

[Team Build 2008 Property Reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/aaronhallberg/archive/2008/02/12/team-build-2008-property-reference.aspx)

I think the property you might be after is $(BinariesRoot) but I am not sure (I tend to build class libraries rather than ASP.NET sites at the moment so don't have a build handy to reference).

Hope that helps,

Martin.